# How do I achieve custom authentication for different types of users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Let's imagine that there is a MVC web application which is going to be consumed by 3 types of users.

User type 1 and type 2 will use their **EMAIL** address as username to login to system while user type 3 will use only an **alpha numeric username** to login since they are not old enough to acquire an email address.

All data models will live under a separate library called Business Objects Tier while data access will separated out to data access tier. Main web application will call out business service classes/repository classes to interact with the database and business logic.

Basic layout of the project is similar to following.

[image]

Now how am I going to achieve custom authentication for this layout? Can I ever use a one custom authentication system to cater for all three types of users?Could you please direct me to a good example?

OR do you think I should separate out web area into three separate projects for each user type WITHOUT keeping under Areas inside one web project? In that way I can user normal authentication model but then how am I going to publish those three web applications into one single domain name? But I don't mind having three separate branches under one domain name.

```
www.mycompany.myapp.com/usertypeone
www.mycompany.myapp.com/usertypetwo
www.mycompany.myapp.com/usertypethree
```

But then how I can deploy those three separate web projects into those three branches? All the custom authentication examples I have seen use simple username and password system but I couldn't find any shows how to use combination of both.

Comment: are you still using passwords for both types of login?

Answer (score 0):

After I posted my question I kept on thinking...
Perhaps I can separate my web area into three separate mvc projects (without having areas under one mvc project) and have 3 different separate authentication systems inside those three separate projects. Then I can publish those three separate projects into three separate subdomains under one single domain.
But I would love to know your expert views on that.

Comment: if u separate the project into three for the three users, then it is not good practice.

Comment: Please read the question carefully, I didn't mean that I was separating the project into three users. I have been talking about three kinds of users.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to the areas approach.

Use a custom AuthorizationFilter. Once registered globally, MVC will let your filter decide whether the request is authorized or not. Your filter can use the Area being accessed to perform that decision.

More info with code [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/957/aspnet-mvc-authentication-filters)

Hope it helps.

Miquel